# Convert collection to array of strings

Tags: laravel-5, export-to-excel

I'm trying to export a query result in Laravel 5 to Excel, but I'm getting the error

> Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

when I use the code below:

```
$equipements=Equipement::all();
    $equipements=collect($equipements)->toArray();
    Excel::create('Inventaire',function($excel) use ($equipements){
        $excel->sheet('Page 1',function ($sheet) use($equipements){
            $sheet->fromArray($equipements);
        });
    })->export('xlsx');
```

But that's not the result I want, I want to specify columns from different tables. Is there any way to convert a collection to array of strings the method  collection->torray return array of objects that's not what I want.

Comment: Can you post the error trace?

Comment: i solved the problem using

foreach ($equipements as $equipement) {
            $data[] = (array)$equipement;
        }

the code below convert array of objects to array of strings

Answer (score 0):

When sending `$equipements` to the `fromArray()` method, you're passing an array to that method. But you're sending the array of all equipements and each single equipement is an instance of the Equipement model.

To send each equipements to it's own row, use the following code:

```
Excel::create('Inventaire', function($excel) {
    $excel->sheet('Page 1', function ($sheet) {
        $equipements = Equipement::all();

        foreach ($equipements as $equipement) {
            $sheet->fromArray($equipement);
        }
    });
})->export('xlsx');
```

One thing to notice is that the `all()` method of a model already returns a `Collection` so no need to `collect()` that data again.